# MySQL SELECT runs multiple times

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select, sum, left-join

When I run my SELECT statement it runs the IFNULL part thrice and the SUM CASE part twice. I know it has something to do with too many LEFT JOIN in the statement. But unable to find a solution to the issue.

It is hard to explain the problem so I have included sqlfiddle link.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/341d9/1)

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(SUM(d.quantity),0) as dispatch, 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.valuefor='alpha' THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END) as alpha,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.valuefor='beta' THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END) as beta 
FROM conversion as c 
LEFT JOIN sale as s ON s.conversionid = c.id 
LEFT JOIN dispatch as d ON d.saleid = s.id 
LEFT JOIN test as t ON t.conversionid = c.id
```

Current Output

```
dispatch    alpha   beta
1800        1400    80
```

Desired Output

```
dispatch    alpha   beta
600         700     40
```

Comment: Your joins are causing a Cartesian product.  You need to do the aggregation *before* doing the joins.

Comment: Yeh that part I figure out that it has to be these join statements. But can't figure out how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate out summing the  dispatch values, and the test values - something like this may give the answer you want :

```
Select A.dispatch,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.valuefor='alpha' THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END) as alpha,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.valuefor='beta' THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END) as beta 
FROM(
  SELECT sum(quantity) AS dispatch, c.id
  FROM conversion as c 
  LEFT JOIN sale as s ON s.conversionid = c.id 
  LEFT JOIN dispatch as d ON d.saleid = s.id
  GROUP BY d.saleid) A
LEFT JOIN test as t ON t.conversionid = A.id
group by A.id;
```

The inner subquery totals the dispatch values, then joins the test amounts.

Comment: There is an error in the query. When you add more values in conversion table, you will notice it doesn't show results for each conversion id.

Comment: See my edit - that may fix it. If not update the sqlfiddle with additional data & I will look again

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(SUM(d.quantity),0) as dispatch, 
  SUM(t.alpha) as alpha,
  SUM(t.beta) as beta 
 FROM conversion as c 
 LEFT JOIN sale as s ON s.conversionid = c.id 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT saleid, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
   FROM dispatch 
   GROUP BY saleid) as d ON d.saleid = s.id 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT conversionid, 
          SUM(CASE WHEN valuefor='alpha' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) as alpha,
          SUM(CASE WHEN valuefor='beta' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) as beta 
   FROM test 
   GROUP BY conversionid) as t ON t.conversionid = c.id
```

The above query performs aggregation on tables `dispatch`, `test`, *before* these tables are used in the `LEFT JOIN` operations.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/341d9/14)

Comment: There is an error in the query. When you add more values in conversion table, you will notice it doesn't show results for each conversion id.